# Rendering Partial View inside another Partial View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one partial view _AgreementsGrid and recevice this:

```
@model List<DataRow>
```

Inside this one I have another called _UsersSearchDDL and receive this:

```
@model List<ConnectWise.Web.Models.ApplicationUser>
```

When I render the partial view i got this error:

[image]

Do you have any ideas why is happening this? I render the dropdown view in another main view without problem but when I try to do inside another partial view... BUMM

Thanks

Comment: as the type of models in your _AgreementsGrid, and _UsersSearchDDL are diffferent, you need to explicitly supply the model to the partial view. @Html.Partial("_UsersSearchDDL", <<object matching to the model>>)

Comment: Thanks @Nirman, Your answer solve my Issue :)

Comment: Cool @Elmer.  I am glad it helped.